# How to sign an Android apk securely without using secrets in github?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, github-actions, signed-apk

https://overflow.buffer.com/2020/05/07/using-github-actions-for-android-continuous-integration-and-delivery/

I read, followed the guide here and managed to setup the Github Action to generate a signed apk. Is it possible to sign an Android apk without using the secrets in Github? If possible I would like to store the keystore jks and the rest of the details eg Alias to a separate cloud server let say Google drive. Will I be able to retrieve the keystore and details and somehow import them into the Github CI script? The ultimate goal that I am trying to achieve is to find the most secure way to sign an apk and I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use GitHub secrets, you can extract the signing information (passwords and alias) to a separate file as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#secure-shared-keystore).

**(All examples are from the link above)**

Create file `keystore.properties` with this content:

```
storePassword=myStorePassword
keyPassword=mykeyPassword
keyAlias=myKeyAlias
storeFile=myStoreFileLocation
```

Read the content of the file in your gradle script:

```
...

// Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
// keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    ...
}
```

Set the signing configuration:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    ...
  }
```

In your CI job, you have to download the keystore and extracted signing information somehow. For example by using `curl`.

That said though, this is still not increasing security. If you're hosting your keystore and signing information publicly, everybody can download it. If you make it only accessible with a password / API key, you will have to provide this password / API key to your CI. Ideally through GitHub secrets.

I don't know your usecase but generally speaking I would recommend using GitHub secrets (or any other secrets functionallity if you use a different CI).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I am aware of this method and it doesn't increase the security like you mentioned. I guess GitHub secrets is the way to go then.